Derived series of a square-free order group stabilizes
I have been studying from these notes on groups, rings and fields by Lenstra and I find myself struggling with problem 1.20 which states the following

Let $G$ be a finite group of squarefree order. Prove that $G^{''}=G^{'''}$.
Where $G^{'}=[G,G]$ and $G^{''}=(G^{'})^{'}$ and so on.

After some unsuccessful attempts I decided to look at the hints which state that

study a naturally defined map $G \ \to Aut(G^{''}/ G^{'''})$

I first had some confusions on what this 'naturally' defined map is but I believe it's cause by the inner automorphisms of $G$ that induce an automorphism in $G^{'}$ and $G^{''}$ and so on..
So hence we get a natural map, and also it's a group action of $G$ on
$G^{''}/G^{'''}$.
I have also observed that $G^{''}/G^{'''}$ is abelian and of square free order too and hence it factors into a product of cyclic groups each of a distinct prime order. So their automorphisms also factor into a direct product of   $U_{p_i}$ 's aswell. And as the order of this is lesser that that of $G$ we can't have an injective map so we have to have a non trivial kernel.
This has been all my progress so far, I would appreciate any help or suggestions from the community.
Thank you

Since ${\rm Aut}(G''/G'')$ is abelian, the restriction to $G'$ of the action of $G$ on  $G''/G'''$ is trivial,  so $G''/G''' \le Z(G'/G''')$.
But $G'/G''$ is a direct product of cyclic groups of prime order so it is cyclic and hence $(G'/G''')/Z(G'/G''')$ is cyclic, which implies that $G'/G'''$ is abelian, and the result follows.

I understood until G"/G''' <= Z(G'/G"') but after that using the fact that G'/G" is cyclic how does it imply that (G'/G''')/Z(G'/G''') is cyclic

From the Third Isomorphism Theorem we have $G'/G'' \cong (G'/G''')/(G''/G''')$.

Thank you for the response. I am grateful
